# What's the difference between creating a mongodb user by passing the role like a document or a string?

Tags: mongodb

What is the difference between passing the roles to mongo's create user command like this

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

and this...

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
    roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

The [mongodb manuals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) comes like the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the role as a string implies that the role should exist in the database the user is being created in.

Passing the role as an object explicitly states which database the role exists in.

For users created in databases other than `admin` the point is moot since these users can only be assigned roles in their database.

For users created in `admin` it is possible to assign roles that exist in other databases.  In this situation it would be required to use the object form.

In your example, both of the roles are built-in roles that exist in the admin database, and the user is being created in the admin database, so either form is acceptable.